# Banco de Dados sendo alterado/Invadido

Tags: banco-de-dados

Não sei se posso fazer essa pergunta aqui, senão puder peço que suspenda a pergunta, ou me avisem que eu a deleto.

Pela segunda vez me deparei com Banco invadido. Quase todos os campos de textos de todas as tabelas do banco foi adicionado o seguinte código no término dos registros:

```
</title>
<style>
    .ao0n {
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(470px,auto,auto,470px);
    }
</style>
<div class="ao0n">quick <a href="http://ironpaydayloans.com">payday loans</a> with small commissions</div>
</title><style>
            .ao0n {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(470px,auto,auto,470px);
            }
        </style><div class="ao0n">quick <a href="http://ironpaydayloans.com">payday loans</a> with small commissions</div>
</title><style>
            .alry {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(410px,auto,auto,410px);
            }
        </style><div class="alry">A payday to get <a href="http://paydayloansforsure.com">fast payday cash loans</a> source you into them.</div>
</title><style>
            .alry {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(410px,auto,auto,410px);
            }
        </style><div class="alry">A payday to get <a href="http://paydayloansforsure.com">fast payday cash loans</a> source you into them.</div>
</title><style>
            .auj {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(441px,auto,auto,441px);
            }
        </style><div class="auj">A much a limited <a href="http://proofpaydayloans.com">payday loans</a> of that banks payday loan.</div>
</title><style>
            .auj {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(441px,auto,auto,441px);
            }
        </style><div class="auj">A much a limited <a href="http://proofpaydayloans.com">payday loans</a> of that banks payday loan.</div>
```

Queria saber se alguém já passou por este problema, ou sabe o porque isso acontece.
E como posso resolver esse problema.

Comment: Isso acontece porque, em algum ponto da sua aplicação, existe uma entrada não-sanitizada de dados. Procure por falhas de segurança conhecidas do(s) framework(s) que você está utlizando, patches correspondentes, e aplique-os.

Comment: Tem cara de sql injection - vcs posseum algum `GET` passando parâmetros ?

Comment: @OnoSendai, Quando entrei na empresa já existia este sistema, e não existe nenhuma Documentação, apenas sei que é um WebSite e está em VB.

Comment: @ederwander, Existem várias páginas acessadas a partir de "/categorias.aspx?id=24" por exemplo.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Na pior das hipóteses, e dependendo do banco de dados, você pode implementar triggers que tentem cancelar qualquer edição estranha, ou na pior das hipóteses limpar o conteúdo inserido.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bom vamos lá!

Pelos comentários eu tenho um palpite forte, você está passando variáveis para o seu aspx, e isso hoje em dia é uma porta de entrada maligna, os "hackers" simplesmente pegam sua variável, no seu caso sua variável `id` e começam a inserir códigos arbitrários de `select/insert/update` isso é chamado de [sql-injection](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), uma alternativa é abolir totalmente o `GET`, a outra é simplesmente filtrar qualquer entrada não esperada em suas variáveis.

Você precisa ter um controle maior dos seus logs, todas as tentativas de sucesso ou não vão estar em seus logs no servidor http (ISS, Apache, etc), perca um tempo analisando estes logs eles vão dizer por onde, qual aspx foi atacado e usado como ponte para inserir os valores indevidamente.

Analise também os logs do seu banco, procure por IP's diferentes que não deveriam fazer acesso.

Cheque seu firewall e garanta que seu banco de dados não tenha acesso externo, se for necessário feche comunicação somente para os ips/domínios necessários e de confiança.

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui com sql-injection, e realmente não existe validação nenhuma de parâmetros. Consegui facilmente deletar uma tabela. Como disse essa aplicação já estava desenvolvida quando entrei aqui na empresa. Meus projetos atualmente são em MVC asp.net com Entity Framework. Ainda assim é possível utilizar sql-injection?

Comment: qualquer sistema pode estar vulnerável, tudo vai depender de como foi construído, se seus sistemas passam parâmetros por `GET` sempre vai existir a possibilidade de uma hora ou outra algum hacker do submundo encontrar um meio de passar pelo seu filtro, o uso de validações de parâmetros é simplesmente o básico e o mínimo que qualquer programador deve/deveria fazer ...

Comment: -1. GET, por si só, não é um problema; nem o uso de tight-coupled ID. Sem higienização dos dados o SGDB pode ser comprometido de qualquer maneira, seja via payload POST/JSON, token de acesso à sessão/operação ou qualquer outro método visando obfuscar o ID físico do registro.

Comment: @OnoSendai, Ou seja a melhor maneira de se precaver é através do SGDB (através de trigger), e não pela aplicação?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo enquanto que o SGDB é a camada onde a qualidade dos dados pode ser mais efetivamente controlada, o controle pode também ser realizado na camada da aplicação. Entretanto, o processo de mapeamento dos pontos de entrada pode ser mais trabalhoso: Enquanto você tem uma tabela que armazena, por exemplo, dados de usuários, você poderá ter N interfaces na aplicação onde esses dados são manipulados.

Answer (score 3):

Isso realmente parece SQL Injection attack.
O problema *per se* não é o get mas SQL dinâmico, que monta o script *on the fly*. Sanitizar dados ajuda mas exitem técnicas hacker de passar aspas usando o código ASCII por exemplo. então a melhor maneira de evitar esse tipo de ataque é parametrizar suas queries.

Se você realmente precisa usar SQL dinâmico e você usa MS Sql tente pesquisar sobre "parametrized dynamic queries" (acredito que outros SGBDs tenham algo equivalente).
(Na pior das hipoteses vc vai trocar suas queries por stored procedures)

Se você usar parâmetros nas suas queries vai evitar que elas sejam hackeadas. Outra coisa que eu vejo que estão tentando explorar é JS script injection mas ai já é outro attack.

**Edit**

Achei uma referência no StackOverflow (para PHP + MySql ) não por acaso parametrizar ainda é a melhor solução

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Cara isso é um injection você tem que fazer um tratamento antes de gravar no banco se não isso vai acontecer sempre se você trabalha com camadas pode tratar no controller se não mude seu método para post e faça uma validação nos campos da requisição antes de inserir no banco.

Comment: Sanitizar os dados ajuda mas o problema é que muitos programadores insistem em usar queries dinâmicas não paramétricas. Se você trocar seu input por parâmetros numa query fixa ao invés de montar a query além de potencial ganho de performance ao roda-la ela ficará praticamente imune a esse problema

Comment: A parametrização do sql também ajuda no desempenho do banco pois ele só compila o sql uma vez

Answer (score 1):

Prezado,
Verifique se não há arquivos suspeitos em sua hospedagem, além de verificar a questão de segurança dos formulários.
Tive um problema parecido com minha hospedagem (Locaweb) e creio que o que gerou isto foi uma invasão aos servidores deles, pois não há nenhuma vulnerabilidade encontrada em nosso sistema.

Comment: Realmente é importante observar isso, pois muitas vezes um intruso não executa simplesmente uma ação de hackeamento, mas deixa alguns scripts maliciosos no servidor para ter as portas abertas sempre que precicsar.